# Return error message vs throw exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I am writing a class library for a asp.net mvc project. Class library will return the entities and executes the basic functions. In the previous project I used a logic like that:

```
public class MyClassLibrary
{
     public Response<ResponseMessage, MyEntity> GetMyEntity()
     {
         //Some code
     }
     public ResponseMessage SaveMyEntity(MyEntity e)
     {
         //Some code
     }
}
public class BaseController:Controller
{
    public ActionResult JsonDataSourceRequest<T>(Func<Response<ResponseMessage, List<T>>> operation, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            Response<ResponseMessage, List<T>> ret = operation();
            if (ret.message.type == ReturnType.OK)
            {
                return Json(ret.result.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
                return ConvertToJson(ret.message);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ResponseMessage m = new ResponseMessage();
            m.type = ReturnType.ERROR;
            m.text = ex.text;
            return ConvertToJson(m);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult PartialView<T>(Func<Response<ResponseMessage, T>> operation)
    {
        //Some code
    }

    public ActionResult Action(Func<ResponseMessage> operation)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
[CustomAuthorize]
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult MyEntityRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return base.JsonDataSourceRequest(() =>
        {
            return MyEntityService.GetAll();
        }, request);
    }
}
```

Here in order to use the BaseController's functions I always return 
    Response 
or
    ResponseMessage

Now I think that I could have custom exception classes and instead of returning a ResponseMessage from all the methods I could throw these exceptions.

I wonder if it is a good practice or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response nvoigt and @darin. Do you think that errors related to project rules are exceptional or not. For example, 
    throw UserCannotBeYoungerThan18("");
is bad?
Should I a motto like "handle everythink that can be handled"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I wonder if it is good practice or not.

No, throwing exceptions to handle non-exceptional flow is bad design. Throwing exceptions comes at a cost and you should avoid them if you can handle your case with a normal flow.

Answer (score 9):

If something is exceptional, you should throw an exception. If something is an expected condition, you should use return values. Only you can know which applies in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. Do you think that errors related to project rules are exceptional or not. For example, 
    throw UserCannotBeYoungerThan18("");
is bad?
Should I a motto like "handle everythink that can be handled"?
(I repeat the question above here because of only one additional user error of stackoverlow)

Comment: If you assume all your data is valid and somebody below 18 is an exceptional case because it should have been handled soemwhere else already, then throw an exception. If your check is the first instance to check this, then I don't think a good part of the populace is exceptional. It's normal to have people below 18 and you should find a normal flow control way to handle this.

Comment: I have got it, your answer was clear and satisfactory, thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 3):

"Throw exceptions instead of returning an error code

Exceptions ensure that failures do not go unnoticed because calling code didn't check a return code."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions